# Two SQL INSERTS depend on each other's result... what's the best approach?

Tags: mysql

I have a stocks table (for products/stocks of a retail store) and a serials table (barcodes issued for each stock).

Basically when new stocks are introduced to the databases, the system issues a serial number for each stock... based on the index/pri autoincrement value of the serials table.

Problem is they both depend on each other...

I'll explain:

```
STOCKS TABLE
stock_id int(11) 
product_name varchar(50)
serial int(30) <--- relies on the serials generated by system, stored in the SERIALS TABLE 


SERIALS
sn_id int(11)
stock_id int(11) <-- relies on the new stocks inserted in the stocks table
serial int(30) <---- serial NO generated for specific stock.
```

Where STOCKS inserted needs to store the Serial Number generated for it, 
as well as the SERIALS generated must be recorded in the table w/ the stock_id (index/pri) of the stocks being inserted..

This basically means 3 SQL statements / new stock:

1. get the next auto inc value of serials table (used to generate the serials properly)
2. insert the stocks into the table with the serials for each
3. get the insert_id of the said stock and insert that into the serials table

This works but I'm wondering if there's a better approach? So far here's what I got running:

1. create a serial_lock file on the home directory (this prevents other scripts from issuing new serial numbers to other stocks , = avoiding conflict on concurrent runs..
2. GENERATE required Serial Nos by getting the next auto_increment value of the serials table and store this in variable for now e.g.

   ```
    $assigned_serials_array[$index] = $prefix . $index; // results in BN-0001 ("BN-" is the prefix and the rest is padded auto inc value incremented per loop
   ```
3. INSERT INTO stocks ,  each stock , get the insert_ID
4. INSERT INTO serials,  a record of the serial being issued to that specific stock
5. after loop is done, delete the lock file

PS.
my original actually does an INSERT already to the serials table, and then does an update on that serials table after a stock_id is generated.. I didn't feel comfortable with that one because of another SQL statement being issued, although it's the safest way though and I don't need to worry about lock file and conflicts.

hmmmm.. any thoughts?

EDIT:
I decided to change my method..
for each SERIAL GENERATED, is a STOCK (stock_id).. I decided to forget about the incremental sequencing of serial numbers 00001 0002 0003

Decided to go ahead and use the stock_id of the specific stock being issued an SN..

so..
get next insert id, generate SN based on that,
INSERT STOCK , w/ generated SN
INSERT SERIAL record, referencing the stock_id to the same next insert id as well..

Done!

I just really wanted to have a perfectly sequenced SN ..

Answer (score 1):

Do not create lock files - this is just wrong.

Instead, DO use transactions. This example in Perl:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql...", "user", "password");
$dbh->begin_work();  # start new transaction
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO serials ..."); # generate new serial
my $new_serial = $dbh->{mysql_insertid};
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO stocks (..., serialno) VALUES (..., $new_serial)");
# do some more work like inserting into other tables
$dbh->commit();  # finally, commit the transaction
```

Note that you need to use InnoDB engine for transactions to work

Comment: ah thanks.. i get your code.. i am actually using transactions.. but then i wanted my SERIALS generated in SEQUENCE w/ the sn_id of each serial, NO SKIPS.. and a rolled back transaction will leave gaps in the sequence ..

Comment: If 2 or more parallel transactions start and acquire few serial ids, but then one rolls back, you cannot avoid having gap. So, don't worry much about gaps - you cannot avoid them with transactions.

Comment: hmmm.. i agree.. im letting go of my obsessive compulsiveness then lolz thanks very much